# Using MySQL, I'd like to update 1 tables id values from another and use ma

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to write a query to update a FK column in table B using the primary key column in table A. If there are duplicate entries in table A, I'd like to use the max id of the duplicate entry to insert into table B.

I have the first part of the query written but I'm unsure about the duplicate entry part.

Here's what I have so far...

```
UPDATE calliope_media.videos v
  JOIN calliope_media.video_ingress_queue viq ON v.provider_unique_id = viq.provider_unique_id
   SET v.video_ingress_id = viq.id;
```

Comment: How come that you have duplicated Primary Keys? If so, that column violates the first commandment for PKs: unicity. Therefore is not a real primary key.

Comment: Can you give a couple examples of the records in table a, and what table b would be both before and after the udpate?  The statement that you have duplicate entries in table A AND that table A has a primary key column seems impossible.

Comment: I don't have duplicate primary keys. Each table has a column called provider_unique_id, and it's possible that that column could contain duplicate values in table A. So if there are duplicate entries for this column is Table A, I'd like to use the one with the greatest id to insert into table B.

Comment: Table a can have rows with duplicate provider_unique_id with values, such as 00000000000004949574 in row 1 and row 2.

Answer (score 0):

This is how your query should look.

```
UPDATE B
SET B.the_column_ID = (SELECT MAX(A.some_ID) 
                       FROM A 
                       WHERE A.matching_value = B.matching_value)
```

This is the overall structure. I haven't adapted to your specific requirements, since I don't fully understand them. But this should get you back on track.